# How do I use Stream Builder to also replace the pushed widgets from Navigator?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using a stream builder that reacts to the Firebase user state. I am in "Landing Screen", and I push "Login Screen" on top of it. After I log in, the Stream Builder replaces the "Landing Screen" with "Discover Screen" correctly. However, the pushed "Login Screen" remains on top of "Discover Screen".

How do I use Stream Builder to also replace the pushed widgets from Navigator?

Here is the code:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AuthService _authService = GetIt.I.get<AuthService>();
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _authService.userStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const LoadingScreen();
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const ErrorScreen();
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return const DiscoverScreen();
          } else {
            return const LandingScreen(); // I push the Login Screen inside this screen
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can create Routes and use Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Routes.HOME);

Comment: Good idea, but it does not solve the problem in the way I asked. I want to keep the navigation stack with the back navigation animation. I just want the entire thing to get replaced only when the state changes in Stram Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show the code of how you push `LoginScreen` on top of `LandingScreen`? If you're using `Navigator`, you'll need to dismiss the `LoginScreen` so that you're rendering the `HomeScreen` which is returning the `DiscoverScreen` (view) inside it.

If that's the case, you can dismiss `LoginScreen` with `Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/homescreen'));`

Except replace the `MediaRoute.withName('...')` with the name of your `HomeScreen` route.

Alternatively, you can use the `StreamBuilder` to cover the state for when login should be showing.

Comment: I already solved it the same way you described it with StreamBuilder and popUntil. Anyway, great explanation. Good job Kyle.

Answer (score 0):

**you will try this code** I think you should try this in your MaterialApp(home: here...) if you wanted to trying in your app in beginning time.

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: _authService.userStream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) => 
authResultSnapshot.connectionState ==
                          ConnectionState.waiting
                      ? LoadingScreen : LandingScreen()
{
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return const LoadingScreen();
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return const ErrorScreen();
      } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return const DiscoverScreen();
      } else {
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
          // your loginScreen();
        } else{
          return const LandingScreen(); // I push the Login Screen inside this screen
        }
        
      }
    },
  ),
```

Comment: The Stream Builder is working fine and it already is in Material App root. I have a different problem. Please read the question.